# How to test that a certain function uses a transaction in Rails and rspec 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, transactions, rails-activerecord

I have a model function that I want to make sure uses a transaction. For example:

```
class Model 
  def method
    Model.transaction do
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

My current approach is to stub a method call inside the block to raise an `ActiveRecord::Rollback` exception, and then check to see if the database has actually changed. But this implies that if for some reason the implementation inside the block changed, then the test would break.

How would you test this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should look at the problem from a different perspective. **Testing whether a function uses a transaction is useless from a behavioral viewpoint**. It does not give you any information on whether the function BEHAVES as expected.

**What you should test is the behavior**, i.e. expected outcome is correct. For clarity, lets say you execute operation A and operation B within the function (executed within one transaction). Operation A credits a user 100 USD in your app. Operation B debits the users credit card with 100 USD.

You should now provide invalid input information for the test, so that debiting the users credit card fails. Wrap the whole function call in an `expect { ... }.not_to change(User, :balance)`.

This way, you test the expected BEHAVIOR - if credit card debit fails, do not credit the user with the amount. Also, if you just refactor your code (e.g. you stop using transactions and rollback things manually), then the result of your test case should not be affected.

That being said, you should still test both operations in isolation as @luacassus mentioned. Also, it is exactly right that your test case should fail in case you made an "incompatible" change (i.e. you change the behavior) to the sourcecode as @rb512 mentioned.

Comment: Or a bit better `expect { ... }.not_to change(User, :balance)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Andrew, I am always on the lookout for these small tweaks :) Changed it in my answer.

Comment: This answer is useful in theory, but there isn't a great way to test concurrency behavior like this. Furthermore, assuming we trust that ActiveRecord's implementation of `transaction` is correct, we need only test that the particular block was passed to it (I don't have a great way to test this either btw...)

Answer (score 23):

A big gotcha needs to be mentioned: When testing transaction, you need to turn off transactional_fixtures. This is because the test framework (e.g Rspec) wraps the test case in transaction block. The after_commit is never called because nothing is really committed. Expecting rollback inside transaction doesn't work either even if you use :requires_new => true. Instead, transaction gets rolled back after the test runs. Ref http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html nested transactions.

Comment: I was aware of that. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: This is a huge gotcha that you need to be aware of when writing specs for code dealing with AR transactions.

Answer (score 7):

Generally you should use "pure" rspec test to test chunks of application (classes and methods) in the isolation. For example if you have the following code:

```
class Model 
  def method
   Model.transaction do
     first_operation
     second_operation
   end
end
```

you should test `first_operation` and `second_operation` in separate test scenarios, ideally without hitting the database. Later you can write a test for `Model#method` and mock those two methods.

At the next step you can write a high level integration test with https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec and check how this code will affect the database in different conditions, for instance when `second_method` will fail.

In my opinion this is the most pragmatic approach to test a code which produces complex database queries.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to enclose your `Model.transaction do ... end` block with `begin rescue end` blocks.

The only way to check for transaction rollbacks is to raise an exception. So your current approach is all good.  As for your concern, a change in implementation would always mean changing the test cases accordingly.  I don't think it would be possible to have a generic unit test case which would require no change even if the method implementation changes.

I hope that helps!

Comment: This is not true for `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` this is handled directly by the transaction, and isn't re-raised.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing the same but now I think perhaps all you need to do is test that the 'transaction' method has been called on the model in one spec and then test the body of the block in other separate specs. Though that would not ensure that the transaction wraps your method calls as your current test does and not some other code that can be in there.

Comment: “test the body of the block” How is this possible?

Comment: Well, you can't call the block specifically, unless you separate it to a function or lambda, but you can call the enclosing function and test that it has done the things you wanted. But as I said, that won't give you any info about whether the things were done in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Given a method as such:

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base 
  private

  def transaction(&block)
    # yield
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(&block)
  end
end
```

In the spec call the private method passing a block which changes the database and then raises:

```
RSpec.describe ApplicationJob do
  describe 'helper methods' do
    subject(:job) { Class.new(described_class).new }

    describe '#transaction' do
      it 'runs block in transaction' do
        block = lambda { FactoryBot.create(:user); raise; }
        expect { job.send(:transaction, &block) rescue nil }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you change the `transaction` method to just `yield` you will see the database is changed even after raising.

Answer (score -6):

Try Testing In rails console Sandbox mode

**rails console --sandbox**

Comment: OP is asking about automated testing (see tags "rspec2" and "rspec-rails"), not checking that it works in the Rails console just once.